# Objective-C: Get supported file extensions for a file type

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ios, macos

I was wondering is there is a way of retrieving in Objective-C (MAC & IOS) all the supported extensions for a file type.

For example, I need to know all the file formats supported for graphics in IOS.

Thanks in advance.

Mikywan.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used it myself but I think you can get what you are looking for from the [Launch Services API](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCIntro/LSCIntro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000999)